# Clion error while running c++ project

Tags: c++, clion

I have a project in C++ which I made myself and I am experiencing a strange error. About 50% of the times I run the project I get an error

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I have no idea why this happens. I am simply running a Dijkstra algorithm which I made myself and printing a couple of lines to the console. The data never change and I am only using a few bytes of memory. I don't understand why does the project manage to run sometimes, and sometimes gives me an error.

Comment: This happens because you've got a bug in your program.... We can't help you more without the program.

Comment: You can paste your code here.

Comment: If it is that small, you could post it here.  That's at the limit for what people will scan,  but it might be something obvious.

Comment: `0xc0000005` is an access violation on Windows.  You're likely referencing a null (or otherwise invalid) pointer.  Running the debugger should point you to the line of code that has the problem.

Comment: Nobody here is going to download your whole project, compile it, and run it.  If it happens 50% of the time, then you should be able to trap it in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph can have up to 9 verticies:

```
Graph *G = new Graph(9);
```

I assume that this means that any particular vertex can have a value from 0 to 8 since the code seems to use the vertex as an index into various vectors.

However, when you create the `previousVertex` vector in `Dijkstra::Dijkstra(Graph *G, int s)`, you give it one less element than the number of vertices for some reason:

```
previousVertex = vector<int>(V - 1); // V is the number of vertices in G
                                     //   which is 9 in your example project
                                     //   so it will have 8 elements and
                                     //   can be indexed with 0-7
```

But you index it with various elements vertex value later:

```
previousVertex[v] = u; // I believe that `v` can have the value 8 at times
```

I think you may be going past the end of the `previousVertex` vector.  I don't know why you're having trouble catching this in a debugger if it crashes 50% of the time.

Comment: I think that must have been the problem, since it now doesn't seem to be crushing anymore. However it still baffles me how it crushed only 50% on the times on "run" and 0 times on the "debugger"

Comment: Try it with MSVC++ (there's a free VS 2015 Community edition).  Visual Studio's C++ library has excellent debug checking of container access and iterator use.  I don't think GCC has those kinds of diagnostics.

Comment: I was indeed using previousVertex[8] though. That was definitely a problem. The reason I had `V-1` is because there is no previous vertex for the starting vertex so I thought lets put in `V-1`, not realizing that this works as index, not only size.